# Не передается значение в аутлет нового вью контроллера

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

У меня есть структура в которой при выполнении появится значение

```
struct Item {
var name: String

init(name: String){
    self.name = name  
}  
}
```

Я создаю массив, чтобы хранить там структуры

```
var items = [Item]()
```

Экземпляры из массива отображаются в таблицу, с этим проблем нет, я хочу, чтобы при нажатии на конкретную ячейку открывался новый ВС:

```
class ItemCellController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()   
}
```

}

И чтобы в его аутлете отображалась соответствующая информация из конкретной структуры.
Для этого я в тейбл вью контроллере создаю функцию переводящую меня на это новое вью:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    let vc = (storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ItemCellVC"))! as? ItemCellController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
```

И в этой же функции пытаюсь затолкать значение из структуры в аутлет:

```
    let item = items [indexPath.row]
    let controller = ItemCellController()
    
    controller.nameLabel?.text = item.name

}
```

И вот собственно проблема: в структуре значение точно есть, а вот в аутлет нового вью контроллера оно не передается, через команду принт отображает значение нил и лейбл не меняется.Как мне его туда затолкать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно вызвать использовать `vc!.nameLabel?.text = item.name` для того, чтобы передать данные, поскольку именно этот (`vc!`) контроллер вы открываете (`pushViewController(vc!, ...)`).

А так получается, что вы создаёте **новый** контроллер, который нигде не используется

```
let controller = ItemCellController()
controller.nameLabel?.text = item.name
```

Comment: Об этом я не подумал, спасибо
Но возникла другая проблема, выбивает 
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
Похоже значение все еще нил. Я так понимаю новый контроллер создается раньше, чем успевает получить значение для своих параметров?

Comment: Удалось решить этот момент путем предварительного создания переменной и передачи значения этой переменной через функцию во вью дидлоад лад аутлету 
`var a = "a"
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        connectOutlet() 
    }
    func connectOutlet() {
        nameLabel.text = a
    }  
}`
И я передаю теперь значение из структуры спера в эту переменную. Но это ведь костыль, как это сделать правильно?

Comment: Вот если я пытаюсь делать МВС шаблон, то модель должна быть отдельная у каждого вью контроллера или одна на все приложение? Мне кажется это могло бы решить мой костыль, сделать его по уместнее